# Required Field Doesn't work for one field but does for other

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I am using a standard validation with MVC, acrossed with my fluent nHibernate

```
    [DisplayName("Product Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Product Name Required")]
    public virtual string ProductName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Price Required")]
    public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Quantity Required")]
    [Range(0, 100000, ErrorMessage = "Must be postive number less then 100000")]
    public virtual int Quantity { get; set; }


    public virtual bool Live { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Attribute> Attribute { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Images> Images { get; set; }
```

This is what makes up my "Product" class... for some reason the name doesnt validate as a required field but things like quantity and Price do.

View has these in it

```
<tr>
                <td>
                    <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductName)%>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProductName, new { @class = "txt" })%>
                    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductName)%>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

and this bit works fine

```
<tr>
                <td>
                    <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price) %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Price, String.Format("{0:F}", Model.Price)) %>
                    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price) %>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

And this is the controller as asked for

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult AddProduct(Product NewProduct)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var ProductRepository = GetRepository<Product>();
            ProductRepository.Add(NewProduct);

            return Redirect("/");
        }

        return View(NewProduct);
    }
```

Comment: What value is sent to the server for this property?

Comment: a Null value is sent to the controller on post back if i leave the productname empty!

Comment: Dude, I did a ctrl+c ctrl+v in an app here and it did work, if you can, post the complete code and configs, the code you show in the post is correct, must be something else. I'll edit my answer if there's something new.

Comment: Additionally, describe the versions of each framework you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found that it was a isssue with not setting the data type

```
[DataType(DataType.Text)]
```

Was missing from my ProductName field!

Answer (score 1):

Just give it a try:

```
[DisplayName("Product Name")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Product Name Required", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
public virtual string ProductName { get; set; }
```

Comment: my System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations doesnt have a definition for "allowEmptyString" ....